# Pytorch 1D tensors expected but got 2D tensors

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I have been working on making neural network from scratch in python. The input tensor is of shape `[400,3]` and target_tensor has the shape `[400]`. I am getting error during taking derivative of weights. Below are functions

```py
    def sigmoid(z):
           return 1 / (1 + torch.exp(-z))

    def nueral_net(data,weights,bias):
           return sigmoid( ( data @ weights ) + bias )

    def loss_function(prediction,actual,m):
           return (-1/m) * (torch.sum(actual * torch.log(prediction) + (1-actual) 
           * torch.log(1- prediction)))

    w = torch.randn(input_tensor.shape[1],1)
    b = torch.randn(1,1)

    predictions = nueral_net(input_tensor.float() , w, b) #Applying model
    loss = loss_function(predictions,target_tensor.unsqueeze(1),400)
    dw = (1/400) * torch.dot(input_tensor,(predictions - target_tensor).T)
```

Running this throws an error.

```
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-26-632338d8fd16> in <module>
          1 predictions = nueral_net(input_tensor.float() , w, b) #Applying model
          2 loss = loss_function(predictions,target_tensor.unsqueeze(1),400)
    ----> 3 dw = (1/400) * torch.dot(input_tensor,(predictions - target_tensor).T)
          4 db = (1/400) * torch.sum(predictions - target_tensor)
          5 #m = input_tensor.shape[0]
    
    RuntimeError: 1D tensors expected, but got 2D and 2D tensor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we see the doc of `torch.dot` :
`torch.dot(input, other, *, out=None)` → `Tensor`
Computes the dot product of two 1D tensors.

NOTE : Unlike NumPy’s dot, torch.dot intentionally only supports computing the dot product of two 1D tensors with the same number of elements.

Parameters
`input` (Tensor) – first tensor in the dot product, must be 1D.
`other` (Tensor) – second tensor in the dot product, must be 1D.

Coming to your question....both `input_tensor` & `(predictions - target_tensor).T` in 2D.
Please make it `1D`

Answer (score 3):

To do matrix multiplation 2D tensor use:

```
torch.matmul(input, other, *, out=None) → Tensor
```

`torch.dot` is for 1D tensors

[Check Official PyTorch Doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html)

Comment: I also was able to use the `@` operator between a 2D and a 1D tensor to do a dot product. **I would refrain from using `torch.matmul` as the actual operation performed (dot product, matrix multiplication, etc.) depends on the dimensions of the input.** So it's harder to know if you accidentally have an error. See [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) for details.